# What is wrong with the following code? It related to EclipseLink 2.1, JPA and Derby

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

following is an excerpt from my entity class

public class PartyRole implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "IDGenerator", strategy = SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "IDGenerator", sequenceName = "IDGenerator", allocationSize = 1)
private long id;
```

I am working in Eclipse and I am using Derby 10.8.2.2

I have created a Sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IDGenerator AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

following is the code in my main method.

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("notesJPA");
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    entityManager.persist(actor);
    //entityManager.persist(director);
    //entityManager.persist(castingManager);
    //entityManager.persist(producer);
    //entityManager.persist(screenWriter);
    //entityManager.persist(storyWriter);
    tx.commit();
```

When I comment out all calls to persist method except the first, things work fine.
When I uncomment the lines, I get the following error.

```
[EL Warning]: 2012-03-07 18:57:03.098--UnitOfWork(2079310344)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL120307183732430' defined on 'PARTYROLE'.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO PARTYROLE (ID, NAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [0, CastingManager, CastingManager]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.ats.data.partyrole.CastingManager@72f6f1b6)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL120307183732430' defined on 'PARTYROLE'.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO PARTYROLE (ID, NAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [0, CastingManager, CastingManager]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.ats.data.partyrole.CastingManager@72f6f1b6)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at amrite.com.jpa.test.LoadPartyRoles.main(LoadPartyRoles.java:38)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL120307183732430' defined on 'PARTYROLE'.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO PARTYROLE (ID, NAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [0, CastingManager, CastingManager]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.ats.data.partyrole.CastingManager@72f6f1b6)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:801)
```

Why am I getting this error? I think I have done all the right things.

For some reason the JPA provider (EclipseLink) is not picking up the next id from the Sequence. Is this a bug? or something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any relationship defined between objects

Comment: There are other objects that have a relationship to this one. This class per se does not have a dependency on any other class, this is almost like static data.

Comment: Looks like it won't allocate the next value from the sequence plus some cascading going on from the other entities. Is this schema generated by eclipselink?